# Build Jenkins job with parameters from CURL / HTTP POST

Tags: php, maven, curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am making an AJAX request to invoke a `PHP(preferably) or similar` file and want that code to `trigger jenkins job remotely`. Also I would like to pass `parameters` to the job that will get triggered. For example, along with AJAX request, my `data` will be holding the value of some vars such as `job` name, `runid`, etc. as shown below:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'runjob.php',
      type: "GET",
      data: { job : job, runid : id },
      success: function(data) {
....
}
```

As per https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API, I have written a small PHP code below:

***runjob.php***

```
 <?php

curl -X POST http://mobile-jenkins.testzynx.com:8080/job/trserver-git/build \
  --data token=12981209380192380129802 \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id","value":runid}, {"name":"profile", "value":"tr-flex.properties"}]}'

?>
```

where `runid` is the var that I will have in my AJAX request code and `trserver-git` is the name of jenkins job.

which follows the syntax as shown in the actual URL:

***syntax from above url***

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --data token=TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'

?>
```

where token is the user API token that I got from my properties in Jenkins.

However, this code(`runjob.php`) does not seem to work and `I am not able to trigger jobs and hence no parameters`.

Later once I am able to trigger the job with parameters passed, `I want to read those parameters to a shell scipt that runs as a part of jenkins job.` For example,

`./runTest.sh -Drunid=$id -Dprofile=$profile` like maven parameters.

Is there a good example on how to achieve this remote parameterized jenkins job trigger and read parameters scenario? `PHP preferred`.

Comment: "does not seem to work" is not a good error description

Comment: My script says could not trigger a remote jenkins job - this is the custom message in my AJAX request.

Comment: And what does the `curl` call emit?

Comment: this: http://imgur.com/ZxxRu4E

Comment: So, it says enough, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope. I have tried with username and password too. Same thing.

Comment: Update: this curl command works for me: `curl -X POST http://build:f9280f220bfb396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/qa-server-git/build 
--data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"RESULTS", "value":"true"}, {"name":"RUN_ID", "value":"1744"}, {"name":"PLAN", "value":"Sample\Plan"}]}'`....How to do this in `PHP`? I know `$cmd='curl....` `exec($cmd,$result);` should work for me. What if I have some vars in the curl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution and this worked for me:

```
$url = "http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/buildWithParameters";     
$data = "POST_RESULTS=true&RUN_ID=".$testrun_id."&CHECK_NAME=SampleAutomatedPlan";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```